# Tricky SQL for a smart search

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I am using a form through a PHP CMS system, that defines custom fields and such.

One of the custom fields allows for an input field which does a smart search. What this means is that when you start typing, it shows the records that match, quite similar to google suggest.

The smartsearch input field relies on a stored mysql search, and this is what I am having trouble with, because it just looks too complex.

I am going to paste the SQl from an existing search, and then explain what I am trying to do.

There are different sql queries in a few columns, as follows:

fromclause

```
((`clients` INNER JOIN `addresstorecord` 
    ON `clients`.`uuid` = `addresstorecord`.`recordid` 
    AND `addresstorecord`.`tabledefid`='tbld:6d290174-8b73-e199-fe6c-bcf3d4b61083' 
    AND addresstorecord.primary='1') 
INNER JOIN `addresses` ON `addresstorecord`.`addressid` = `addresses`.`uuid`)
```

displayfield:

```
IF(clients.company != '', 
   CONCAT(clients.company,
          IF(clients.lastname != '' OR clients.firstname != '', 
             CONCAT(' (',
                    IF(clients.lastname != '', clients.lastname, '{blank}'),
                    ', ',
                    IF(clients.firstname != '', clients.firstname, '{blank}'),
                    ')'),
             '')
          ),
   IF(clients.lastname != '' OR clients.firstname != '',
      CONCAT(IF(clients.lastname != '', clients.lastname, '{blank}'),
             ', ',
             IF(clients.firstname != '', clients.firstname, '{blank}')),
      ''))
)
```

secondaryfield:

```
IF(addresses.city != '' OR addresses.state !='' OR addresses.postalcode != '',
  CONCAT(IF(addresses.city != '', addresses.city, ''),
         ', ',
         IF(addresses.state != '', addresses.state, ''),
         ' ',
         IF(addresses.postalcode != '', addresses.postalcode, '')),
  'unspecified location')
```

classfield

```
clients.type
```

searchfields

```
clients.company, clients.firstname, clients.lastname
```

filterclause

```
clients.inactive=0
```

I am having trouble understanding how these queries actually work. displayfield and secondaryfield in particular seem very redundant.

i don´t think my needs are so different from how the current example smartsearch field works...just instead of clients i want guests, and instead of address, i just want it to match firstname, lastname or passport number.

I wonder if I even need secondaryfield in that case?

In particular, the inner join in the fromclause confuses me, as I don´t think I need to do that as all the guest information is in one table...

Any assistance here is much appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: could you provide the entire query as a block so we can see what's actually being queried from the DB?

Comment: how would I do that? I don´t think I can...I think the smartsearch field does different queries depending on what is typed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reformatted your code samples with some indenting so it's easier to read.  They were very long and scrolling horizontally it's hard to tell what's going on.

Something like this appears to do nothing:

```
IF(addresses.state != '', addresses.state, '')
```

I would guess it was written by someone who didn't understand how NULL works in SQL, or someone who is accustomed to Oracle, where NULL and '' are equivalent.

Displayfield and secondaryfield have different content.  Displayfield shows the person's company and name, whereas secondaryfield shows the person's address, state, and postal code.  These are not redundant.

The complexity comes from trying to handle blank or unspecified content.

Comment: Thankyou for the reformatting.

The code definitely does work, and was designed to work with MySQL.

I think it has something to do with that since it is a smartsearch, what I have posted is not the entire query, rather the query would be made from part of what I have poested and part of what I type in the field as I type it.

Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding any documentation and figuring this out, and am working somewhat blind.

Would you have any suggestions on how I can figure out what queries are actually being made to the database? Can mysql be configured to log all queries?

Comment: I agree some unecesary complexity could be avoided using `IFNULL(addresses.city, ''` instead of `IF(addresses.city != '', addresses.city, '')` for example.

Comment: @Jacob: I think you're right, probably the smartsearch system uses and modify these parts of queries to build one based on the answers/choices on the form. this is why there are so many options that seems unecessary. They may be used depending on the choices for the search. To log mysql queries, you can insert in `/etc/my.cnf`: 
`[mysqld]` section: `log=/tmp/mysql.log`
mysql needs rights to create and write to the file. Make it only readable to mysql as it will log ALL queries, including passwords and to use it only during developing, debugging as it will become very big quickly

Comment: +1 to @laurent-rpnet.  You can read more about MySQL logging here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-logs.html